# How to export files from server to client - Java RMI

Tags: java, rmi

I am new to Java RMI and I am simply trying to run a "Hello World" program (code is shown at the end of the message)

Basically, I have a remote class, a remote interface, and a server class in one of my computers and a client class in another computer. 
I am trying to get a "hello" message from the server using the client. 
The problem is that I cannot compile the client and get it running if I don't have the remote interface and the stub in the same directory where the client is, and at the same time I cannot run the server if I don't have those in the same directory that the server is.

I compiled the server/remote class/interface using javac and then using the rmic compiler.
"rmic Hello".

I am wondering how I could get this to work without having to have all the files in both computers (which is why I want to make it distributed)

Thanks in advance!

Code:

Remote Interface:

```
import java.rmi.*;  

 //Remote Interface for the "Hello, world!" example.  
public interface HelloInterface extends Remote {  
  public String say() throws RemoteException;  
}
```

Remote class:

```
import java.rmi.*;  
import java.rmi.server.*;  

public class Hello extends UnicastRemoteObject implements HelloInterface {  
  private String message;  

  public Hello (String msg) throws RemoteException {  
    message = msg;  
  }  

  public String say() throws RemoteException {  
    return message;  
  }  
}
```

Client:
import java.rmi.*;

```
public class Client  
{  
    public static void main (String[] argv)  
    {  
        try  
                 {  
            HelloInterface hello= (HelloInterface) Naming.lookup(host);  //the string        representing the host was modified to be posted here  
            System.out.println (hello.say());  
        }  
        catch (Exception e)  
        {  
            System.out.println ("Hello Server exception: " + e);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Server:

```
  public static void main (String[] argv) {  
    try {  
      Naming.rebind ("Hello", new Hello ("Hello, world!"));  
      System.out.println ("Hello Server is ready.");  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
      System.out.println ("Hello Server failed: " + e);  
    }  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to simply create identical source at both / either end.

Answer (score 0):

> am wondering how I could get this to work without having to have all the files in both computers

You can't. You have to distribute the required class files to the client.

> (which is why I want to make it distributed)

*Non sequitur.*